# Calculating screen coverage

Tags: image, image-processing, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Here's my issue: I'm writing a web-design related dissertation, and I'm looking to calculate the percentage of the image taken up by certain web elements. I have a collection of 500 screenshots of websites, and I'm looking for a way to quickly and methodically work through them calculating how much space is taken up by a single element.

As an example, I've attached a screenshot below to illustrate my thinking. The red outlined area indicates the total area I'd need to measure, and the green outline indicates a highlighted element (in this case the 'Search' button).

What would be the best way to do this? I'm on a MacBook Air running Mojave 10.14.5, and free software would be preferable.

Edit (To answer comments): I am marking up by hand. In this case I just used the Preview tool on Mac and saved the markup over the original image.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you marking/annotating the areas by hand? Using what tool?

Comment: A suggestion is to use OpenCV. You can find the contour of the green outlined area, determine area with `findContours()` and compare it with the area of the entire image

Comment: You should do it when you take the screenshot, you can get those numbers with javascript easy enough. You  want puppeteer or selenium for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with **ImageMagick** which you can install on macOS with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

So, starting with this image as annotated using macOS Preview and annotation in lime green with a transparent fill:

[image]

Then I would save this script in my HOME directory as `analyze`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
   >&2 echo "Usage: analyze IMAGE"
   exit 1
fi

image="$1"

# Assume image is annotated in lime green - you can set any RGB colour with syntax like  "rgb(10,20,30)"
annocolour="lime"

# Calculate percentage of image inside annotation box, each line corresponds to a line of code:
# - make everything not lime green into black (image is just pure black with green annotation now)
# - add a 1-pixel black border for the floodfill in the next step to flow around
# - floodfill everything outside the annotation box with lime green starting at 0,0 in top-left corner
# - remove 1-pixel border we added above
# - make everything lime green into white (i.e. everything outside the annotation box becomes white)
# - invert the image so the contents of annotation box are white and everything else is black and print image name and mean, which is the percentage white

convert "$image" -fuzz 10% -fill black +opaque "$annocolour" \
   -bordercolor black -border 1                              \
   -fill "$annocolour" -draw "color 0,0 floodfill"           \
   -shave 1x1 -alpha off                                     \
   -fill white -opaque "$annocolour"                         \
   -negate -format "%f,%[fx:mean*100]\n" info:
```

Now, just necessary one time, make that script executable:

```
chmod +x $HOME/analyze
```

Then I can calculate the percentage of any image inside the lime-green annotated area with:

```
$HOME/analyze grab.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
grab.png,2.85734
```

which means 2.8% of the image is inside the green box.

---

If you have 500 PNG images, you will want a loop like this:

```
for f in *.png; do $HOME/analyze "$f" ; done
```

**Keywords**: annotate, annotation area, image, image processing, ImageMagick, macOS